# Failing azure git deploys due to jquery typings errors

Tags: jquery, angular, azure, typescript-typings, syncfusion

I'm building a scheduling application that uses the syncfusion scheduler component (an ng2 wrapper around a jquery plugin essentially). Following their documentation I've added both jquery and the associated TS typings, and everything is working fine locally after some upgrading of npm versions.

When git deploying to azure for testing and demoing, my builds are failing. Initially the error was as follows:

> Cannot find module 'validate-npm-package-license'

This isn't a package I've had to install, but I presume it's necessary to prove that my company own a license for these controls (which we do). I've got an open support call with syncfusion but hoping to progress this without waiting too long! Not sure if it's a valid fix but adding a prepublish script of:

```
"prepublish": "npm install -g validate-npm-package-license"
```

seems to have fixed this issue. However, the next build failed with no real reason given, other than the process exited. In past experiences the occasional azure git deploy has failed randomly like this before passing on a redeploy so I tried that, but now receive hundreds of jquery typings errors such as:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:41:40 
>             TS1005: ',' expected.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:4332:52 
>             TS1139: Type parameter declaration expected.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:35:23 
>             TS2314: Generic type 'JQueryStatic' requires 2 type argument(s).

etc etc.

I've already had to downgrade to a much older version of these typings to fix local build errors, but I'm unsure as to why this is now failing in azure.

I've forced the azure node version to 8.0.0 with the environment variable, and this then yields an npm version of 5.0.0, and this is my current package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "scheduler",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "npm install -g validate-npm-package-license",
    "build": "webpack",
    "copy-ej": "xcopy node_modules\\syncfusion-javascript\\Content\\ej wwwroot\\dist\\ej /y /s /i",
    "postinstall": "npm run copy-ej",
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.5",
    "@types/ej.web.all": "^15.2.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.42",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.11",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "angular2-universal": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-universal-patch": "^0.2.1",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.17",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "ej-angular2": "^15.2.43",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.7.0",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "syncfusion-javascript": "^15.2.43",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.37",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on what might be causing this?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The similar issue can be found here: [@types/jquery giving breaking solution while Gulp build](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/17239).

As @leonard-thieu pointed out,

> `@types/jquery` requires TypeScript 2.3 or higher.   If you're getting
>   errors similar to
>
> - error TS2314: Generic type 'Deferred' requires 4 type argument(s).
> - error TS1005: ',' expected.
>
> You need to upgrade to `typescript@2.3` or later.

You may also need to upgrade `@types/jquery` to `3.2.5`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've upgraded to typescript@2.4.1 and @types/jquery@3.2.5  and still getting a tonne of ',' expected errors :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in Syncfusion components.

We are unable to reproduce the reported issue “ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:41:40 TS1005: ',' expected.”  at out end with jquery.d.ts@2.0.34. We have created the ASP .NET Core Angular sample using Visual Studio 2015 and published it using Azure app service. For your convenience we have attached sample in below link.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Asp.Net-Sample719743832.zip)

Refer to the below link for published above angular app.

http://aspnet-sample20170704125558.azurewebsites.net/

For your reference we have attached log file of published app.

[log-file](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/txt/publish-log-59741310.txt)

If you are still facing the issues share the sample application that you have tried to published, which help use to investigate further and provide you solution at the earliest.